# Can't save modelform with Choices Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I've got the following model:

```
class Unit(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ("1", "Strecke"),
        ("2", "Zeit"),
        ("3", "anderes")
    )
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    factor = models.FloatField()
    base_unit = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=3)
```

Using a simple ModelForm:

```
class UnitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Unit
        fields = '__all__'
```

After running `form.is_valid()` I get the error: "Please choose a valid choice. 2 is not a valid choice". What am I missing here, isn't 1, 2 or 3 exactly the value I need to save the form, because those are the expected values from the type-field of the model to be saved in the database?

Comment: Use CharField instead of IntegerField. Also avoid using type (builtin function name) as variable name

Comment: Your choice options are defined as `str`, but your field is of `IntegerField`. Be consistent and use either `str` or `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, "Strecke"),
        (2, "Zeit"),
        (3, "anderes")
```

In your template don't forget to use this format to display the value instead of the key

get_**type**_display